# Print bytes to hex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to encode string to bytes.

To convert to byes, I used `byte.fromhex()`

```
>>> byte.fromhex('7403073845')
b't\x03\x078E'
```

But it displayed some characters.

How can it be displayed as hex like following?

```
b't\x03\x078E' => '\x74\x03\x07\x38\x45'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python `repr` can't be changed. If you want to do something like this, you'd need to do it yourself; `bytes` objects are trying to minimize spew, not format output for you.

If you want to print it like that, you can do:

```
from itertools import repeat

hexstring = '7403073845'

# Makes the individual \x## strings using iter reuse trick to pair up
# hex characters, and prefixing with \x as it goes
escapecodes = map(''.join, zip(repeat(r'\x'), *[iter(hexstring)]*2))

# Print them all with quotes around them (or omit the quotes, your choice)
print("'", *escapecodes, "'", sep='')
```

Output is exactly as you requested:

```
'\x74\x03\x07\x38\x45'
```

Comment: you can override `sys.displayhook`, to change how `bytes` are displayed in REPL.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Eew... Learn something new and terrible every day. Don't get me wrong, that's cool. But the idea of replacing the normal `repr` with something else thanks to code defined somewhere completely different scares me; great way to get horribly confused when you expect one thing, and get something completely different. You have given me amusing ideas for pranking people with modified `PYTHONSTARTUP` files though. ;-)

Comment: It is not such an outlandish idea that binary data should be displayed as binary (hex repr). I understand that many protocols mix freely ascii text and binary data and that there is Python 2 legacy where text and binary data often represented as the same `str` type. It is debatable what `repr(b'\x74')` should be if it were designed from scratch (why do you think `"b't'"` inside e.g., an image data is better than `"b'\x74'"`?)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The "Eew" wasn't at the idea of an alternate way to do the `repr`. It was at the idea of code that was taking complete control of the REPL displayback such that the normal behavior you expect (seeing the `repr`) is replaced with "whatever the displayhook happens to do" (which no obvious indication that it's happening; mistakes could silently drop/corrupt data). I agree that the choice between pure escape codes and partial ASCII is mostly arbitrary (though in the case where the binary data really is ASCII, it's a heck of a lot more readable to stick with partial ASCII).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Actually, just ignore what I'm trying to say, and read this post (and the related posts linked in the first paragraph), [Don’t use global state to manage a local problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873/), to get an idea of why it bothers me. Solving local problems (I want these specific `bytes` objects displayed in a different way) with a global solution (I'll take complete control of the displayback machinery for all objects) is worrisome.

Comment: It is unrelated to the current issue. A user has a right to customize the environment and `sys.displayhook` is the appropriate place for that. Real life example: IPython overrides `sys.displayhook` to use `WriteConsoleW()`, to display Unicode in Windows console.

Comment: New link: [Don't use global state to manage a local problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873).

Answer (score 7):

> I want to encode string to bytes.

`bytes.fromhex()` already transforms your hex string into bytes. Don't confuse an object and its text representation -- REPL uses `sys.displayhook` that uses `repr()` to *display* bytes in ascii printable range as the corresponding characters but it doesn't affect the value in any way:

```
>>> b't' == b'\x74'
True
```

> Print bytes to hex

To convert bytes back into a hex string, you could use `bytes.hex` method since Python 3.5:

```
>>> b't\x03\x078E'.hex()
'7403073845'
```

On older Python version you could use `binascii.hexlify()`:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b't\x03\x078E').decode('ascii')
'7403073845'
```

> How can it be displayed as hex like following? `b't\x03\x078E' => '\x74\x03\x07\x38\x45'`

```
>>> print(''.join(['\\x%02x' % b for b in b't\x03\x078E']))
\x74\x03\x07\x38\x45
```