# Increment a Variable With an Unknown Type

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, pwntools

Within the pwntools library in Python 2.7, an address is declared as `address = p64(0x7fffffff0000)`. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to increment this address, though I keep running into conversion errors during the edition. I started out with the basic stuff, initially:

```
from pwn import *
address = p64(0x7fffffff0000)    # starting hex value
for i in range(0, 65535):     # how many times you want to increment

    i +=1
    address = p64(0x7fffffff0000 + i)        # increment varhex by 1
    print address
```

Though the output, rather than incrementing it in a hexadecimal fashion incremented in a unicode fashion like so:

```
...
_-\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00
`-\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00
a-\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00
...
```

Does anyone know how to increment this variable to have the output appear as:

```
...
\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00
\x02\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00
...
\x00\x01\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00
...
```

Comment: Appear as...? You forgot to include it. Odds are the `p64` type is just printing it little endian, in which case that increment is correct.

Comment: @ShadowRanger My bad, thank you. Just edited the question, the output at the bottom is the desired output as opposed to the unicode-intertwined output.

Comment: What do you mean by "incremented it in a unicode fashion?" You now say the output you provided what you want, what it is displaying instead?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've updated it again with the output generated by the code in the OP, apologies and hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: It looks like `p64` is just a simple converter from `int` to `str`, so what you're really asking for is a Python 2 equivalent of [my answer to "Print bytes to hex"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690143/364696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p64` is just a trivial converter to `str`. When a `str` is printed on Python 2, the `repr` will display printable ASCII characters in preference to the `\x` escapes; if you want to prevent this, you need to explicitly write it in the form you prefer. A simple fixer might be:

```
from future_builtins import map, zip  # Gets Python 3 generator based version of map/zip
from itertools import repeat
import binascii

def bytes_to_x_escapes(s):
    hexstring = binascii.hexlify(s)
    escapecodes = map(''.join, zip(repeat(r'\x'), *[iter(hexstring)]*2))
    return ''.join(escapecodes)
```

With this fixer, you can change your `print`s to:

```
print bytes_to_x_escapes(address)
```

and it will display the way you expect.

Comment: Note: In my own local tests, I can't reproduce your exact behavior (if I `print` without `repr`ing, it prints blanks and various garbage, not the `\x` escapes; it's possible this behavior might differ on different operating systems, locales, etc.). But what you're showing is *very* close to the `repr` (just without the quotes around it), so I'm answering on the assumption that that is roughly what you were doing.